# Compare files names regardless of extension in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a node script that currently spits out two arrays:

```
$ yarn run header:test
yarn run v0.22.0
$ ./bin/create_header.js 
[ 'LucidEventIcon.md', 'LucidStates.md' ] [ 'LucidEventIcon.js', 'LucidStates.js' ]
```

What I would like to do is use some kind of find method to say:

"LucideEventIcon.md should match the LucidEventIcon.js", what I care about is matching on name. I need to keep the file extension so I can, later, prepend the contends of the `.md` to the `.js`

**How can I match on name, regardless of extension? while looping over the first and checking the second array?**

Expected result should be true for both elements in the first array, they should match to the two JS files in the second array.

Comment: You can use the `myArray.map` function, create a new virtual arrays e compare those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own little function for comparing the base name (without file extension) and then just loop through the first array calling this function for both arrays.  The `path` module can be used to parse out just the base name (without extension or path).

```
const path = require('path');

function compareFileNames(f1, f2) {
    let name1 = path.parse(f1).name;
    let name2 = path.parse(f2).name;
    return name1 === name2;
}
```

It's not clear to me exactly what type of output you want, but you could create an array of booleans that tell you what matches.  If the two arrays are `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
let results = arr1.map(function(f1, index) {
    let f2 = arr2[index];
    return typeof f2 === "string" && compareFileNames(f1, f2);
});
```

If you're just trying to see if they all match:

```
let match = arr1.every(function(f1, index) {
    let f2 = arr2[index];
    return typeof f2 === "string"  && compareFileNames(f1, f2);
});
```

Comment: For the second function where you see if they all match, how do you know that the bound of both arrays are the same? I supposed you'll be matching undefined, but I would preface that with a simple condition.

Comment: @tsturzl - If it is possible the arrays are not the same length, then that should be tested for.

Answer (score -2):

Updated isArraysEqual function to not modify Array.prototype.

```
   function isArraysEqual(arr1, arr2, strict) {
    if (!arr1 || !arr2)
        return false;

    if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] instanceof Array && arr2[i] instanceof Array) {
            if (!isArraysEqual(arr1[i], arr2[i], strict))
                return false;
        }
        else if (strict && arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!strict) {
            return isArraysEqual(arr1.sort(), arr2.sort(), true);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

const mdFiles = [ 'LucidEventIcon.md', 'LucidStates.md' ].map((file)=>file.split('.')[0]);
const jsFiles = [ 'LucidEventIcon.js', 'LucidStates.js' ].map((file)=>file.split('.')[0]);

const isEqual = isArraysEqual(mdFiles, jsFiles, false);
```

Comment: Don't add prototype methods to global objects, it looks cool but its bad design.

Comment: @tsturzl So that's the reason for the down vote?  What's the problem of extending Array object? If you use it in a module, it will not affect other module or global namespace

Comment: FYI, modifying an `Array` prototype is NOT local to a module.  `Array` is a global.

Comment: That makes several assumptions. The runtime environment, the module system used(or if there even is one being used).

Regardless, you're still polluting a top level namespace. You get in the habit of doing this and you happen to write 2 prototypes both named `equal` on the Array object, now you have something you thought was completely unrelated breaking. This is hackish, and what do you gain? The illusion of organized code?

Comment: @tsturzl I've updated my answer, but I think it's no problem for me to add a equal function to Array.prototype because I know what I'm doing, and you were right it's a bad practice.